# SQL statement that uses lookup based on table value

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, lookup

I need hand to structure a complex SQL statement (well at least complex for me!)

I have three tables, below are the structures.

Customer Table:
Customer ID, Customer Name, Address, Tariff*

APRW14_FFA68878_Calls:
CLI, ChargeCode, Duration, Time Band

(Tariff Name) – Multiple tables with different Tariffs
ChargeCode, Peak, Off-Peak, Weekend, Setup, Minimum

*Each customer has their own Tariff, as defined in the Customer table – There is then a corresponding Tariff table which holds the tariff detail.

What I am trying to do is to write a dynamic statement, so that the query looks up the tariff name from the customer table and then pulls data from the corresponding Tariff table.

Here is my code so far.

```
UPDATE [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] 
SET    [APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Sell Price] = [*Query to pull back tariff name from Customer table here*].[Peak]/60*[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Duration (secs)]
FROM   [Test].[dbo].[DaisyRates_May2014]
INNER JOIN [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[ChargeCode] = [Test].[dbo].[*Query to pull back tariff name from Customer table here*].[Chargecode]
```

I have put "*Query to pull back tariff name from Customer table here*" in the code where I need to pull back the Tariff name based on the Customer table.

I hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Looks like it's probably SQL Server. Also, having a table per tariff just doesn't seem like the correct way to structure your database; are you able to modify the database structure?

Comment: Try and make a select which selects the correct Sell Price. Then you should be able to turn that into an update without the need for subqueries. Most all updates can first be written as a equivalent select, which makes it much easier to visualize the query (imo)

Comment: Thanks, but if I could select the correct Sell Price then I would not have an issue. Can you provide an example as to how I can pull back the correct Sell Price based on a dynamic Tariff value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a store procedure with pseudo code like this...

```
select distinct tariff from customer table;
for each tariff name as current tariff name
    update customer set (select ... from current tariff name table)... 
    where customer.tariff = current tariff name
end for
```

Comment: Can you expand this answer, specifically for SQL-Server. This appears to be the wrong syntax for my RDBMS. Thanks